# Odd atoi(char *) issue

Tags: ios, c, atoi

I'm experiencing a very odd issue with `atoi(char *)`. I'm trying to convert a `char` into it's numerical representation (I know that it is a number), which works perfectly fine 98.04% of the time, but it will give me a random value the other 1.96% of the time.

Here is the code I am using to test it:

```
int increment = 0, repetitions = 10000000;
for(int i = 0; i < repetitions; i++)
{
    char randomNumber = (char)rand()%10 + 48;
    int firstAtoi = atoi(&randomNumber);
    int secondAtoi = atoi(&randomNumber);
    if(firstAtoi != secondAtoi)NSLog(@"First: %d - Second: %d", firstAtoi, secondAtoi);
    if(firstAtoi > 9 || firstAtoi < 0)
    {
        increment++;
        NSLog(@"First Atoi: %d", firstAtoi);
    }
}
NSLog(@"Ratio Percentage: %.2f", 100.0f * (float)increment/(float)repetitions);
```

I'm using the `GNU99` C Language Dialect in XCode 4.6.1. The first if (for when the first number does not equal the second) never logs, so the two atoi's return the same result every time, however, the results are different every time. The "incorrect results" seemingly range from -1000 up to 10000. I haven't seen any above 9999 or any below -999.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

---

EDIT:

I have now changed the character design to:

```
char numberChar = (char)rand()%10 + 48;
char randomNumber[2];
randomNumber[0] = numberChar;
randomNumber[1] = 0;
```

However, I am using:

```
MAX(MIN((int)(myCharacter - '0'), 9), 0)
```

to get the integer value.

I really appreciate all of the answers!

Comment: why you use `atoi` anyway? you already have `[NSString intValue]`

Comment: @xlc It's because its a little insane to convert the `char` into an `NSString` and then into an `int`.

Comment: you don't need `atoi` to convert char to int. `char c = '1'; int i = c - '0';`

Comment: @xlc I appreciate that, but I have that in my question, already. I was just hoping for something a bit cleaner than that solution.

Comment: @RileyE: "cleaner" how?  There is nothing hackish about subtracting `'0'` from a numeric `char` to get its integral value.  It is a well defined and guaranteed operation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`atoi` expects a string. You have not given it a string, you have given it a single `char`.  A string is defined as some number of characters *ended by* the null character.  You are invoking UB.

From the docs:

> **If str does not point to a valid C-string**, or if the converted value would be out of the range of values representable by an int, it causes undefined behavior.

Want to "convert" a character to its integral representation?  Don't overcomplicate things;

```
int x = some_char;
```

A `char` is an integer already, not a string.  Don't think of a single `char` as text.

Comment: If the char contains a character from 0-9, the conversion would be `int x = some_char - '0'`. But otherwise absolutely correct, +1

Comment: I guess I will just have to do something along the lines of `MAX(MIN((int)myCharacterNumber - 48, 9), 0)`. I was hoping to find a better solution. Also, I'm not too familiar with how I would make a c-string with the character. Would I just do something along the lines of `char cString[] = (char)malloc(sizeof(char) * 2); cString[0] = myCharacterNumber; cString[1] = '\0';`?

Comment: @RileyE Save yourself the trouble and just do `char cString[2];`. Assign `cString[1]` to `0` and `cString[0]` to the char value.

Comment: @ThePhD Okay. That's great. Thank you! What would `cString[0]` be if I didn't assign it?

Comment: I really appreciate the explanation, Ed! Unfortunately, I only have one upvote.

Comment: @RileyE It would be whatever happened to be in the place the compiler got the memory from, i.e. GARBAGE.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, `atoi` expects a null-terminated string (see the [documentation here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi)).

You're passing in a single stack-based value, which does not have to be null-terminated. I'm extremely surprised it's even getting it right: it could be reading off hundreds of garbage numbers into eternity, if it never finds a null-terminator. If you just want to get the number of a single char (as in, the numeric value of the char's human-readable representation), why don't you just do `int numeric = randomNumber - 48` ?

Comment: `atoi` is likely to return a "valid" value when it sees a non-digit character. But `atoi()` does essentially no error checking, so it shouldn't be used unless you're *certain* that you're passing it a pointer to a valid string.

Comment: @ThePhD: I didn't mean to imply that it won't go nuts. If you give it an invalid argument, the behavior is undefined, and "going nuts" is exactly what it can do. I was merely speculating on how some implementations of `atoi()` are *likely* to behave for some arguments.